# Error when building Xamarin project

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, parse-server

I'm receiving this error everytime i try to build my xamarin project

```
Can not resolve reference: `Parse`, referenced by `Project`. Please 
add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Parse`, or remove the reference 
to `Project`.   Project.Android
```

So far I've tried:

- Deleting all the folders in packages > restarting VS2017
- Running VS2017 as Admin

None of those worked, anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does Parse come from?

Comment: @Cheesebaron what do you mean? I installed via SDK Manager for the entire solution

Comment: You have referenced some Parse dll. Where does it originate from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the Android version to 10.0 from 11.0, uninstalled and reinstalled Parse again and it worked.

**Edit**

Stopped working again. Upgraded to the 2.0.0 version as per this link - https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/303

**Edit**

Stopped working again. Went back to the 1.7 version but this time didn't use the Nuget package. Extracted Android and IOS dlls and added them manually as references. Working now.

**Edit**
Download Parse-1.7.0.zip
from https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET/releases/tag/1.7.0

Extract the contents.

```
Add Parse.Android.dll to the Android project. 
Add Parse.iOS.dll to iOS project. 
Add Parse.dll to Assemblies in the main project.
```